# big query external tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, external-tables

There are many files which going to be land on gcs bucket daily. We have to merge them all and create a new file copied to new location.

I can do this with reading all the files which starts from config*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE `test-project.TEMP_PROCESSING.test_external_table`
OPTIONS (
  format = 'CSV',
  uris = ['gs://test-greenplum-bq-bucket/test_input/config*.csv'],
  skip_leading_rows = 1
);
```

file names will be like below

```
gs://test-greenplum-bq-bucket/test_input/config-7621049c2008e19dae82017fa8d5f189-20230801-1690846454-627484-28180770-66nwd.csv
```

I was trying to get the files matching pattern

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE `test-project.TEMP_PROCESSING.test_external_table`
OPTIONS (
  format = 'CSV',
  uris = ['gs://test-greenplum-bq-bucket/test_input/config-*-'||regexp_replace(cast(current_date as string),'-','')||'-*.csv'],
  skip_leading_rows = 1
);
```

am getting below error.

```
Found unsupported function call 'ARRAY[...]'; failed to evaluate 'uris' in external table OPTIONS
```

I did try execute immediate but no luck.

```
begin
declare gcs_bucket_location  string;
set gcs_bucket_location = 'gs://test-greenplum-bq-bucket/test_input/test_file_*-'||regexp_replace(cast(current_date as string),'-','')||'-*.csv';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test-project.TEMP_PROCESSING.test_external_table`
OPTIONS (
  format = 'CSV',
  uris = [%gcs_bucket_location],
  location = 'EU',
  skip_leading_rows = 1
  );
""",gcs_bucket_location);
end
```

getting this.

```
Found unsupported function call 'ARRAY[...]'; failed to evaluate 'uris' in external table OPTIONS
```

feel free to suggest if there is another approach to do so.

[reference article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/merge-clean-transform-your-csvs-easily-with-bigquery-3a73c0c26d57) `https://medium.com/google-cloud/merge-clean-transform-your-csvs-easily-with-bigquery-3a73c0c26d57`

Comment: Can I please clarify, in the regex are you trying to only select the files starting with config and on current_date?

Comment: @BihagKashikar yes

Comment: I am suggesting another option in answer soon - it is without pattern matching but in two parts - 1) load all files with config* 2) export data and add datetime to generate file at new location. assuming this is your ultimate aim

Comment: I have updated answer with suggestion to use pseudo column

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation below, it appears the pattern matching supported on below cases only.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-cloud-storage#wildcard-support

Therefore, given the limited support, I recommend a workaround to you.

If your goal is to merge all files, and then generate the file at another location, then I suggest two step workaround.

Once once you load all config* files, you can query the data using pseudo [column](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-cloud-storage-data#query_the_file_name_pseudo-column) to identify records belonging to file name is GCS. This way you can then selectively export data for given dated files to another location.

```
   -- Step 1: Load data with file pattern matching
    CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE `silicon-comfort-329203.YOUR-DATASET.test_external_table`
    OPTIONS (
      format = 'CSV',
      uris = ['gs://YOUR-BUCKET/config-*.csv'],
      skip_leading_rows = 1
    );
    
    --- Step 2: Export the data loaded in previous step with EXPORT command with date qualifiers suffix
    EXPORT DATA 
      OPTIONS(
      uri='gs://YOUR-BUCKET/MERGE_config_FILE_'||CAST(current_date() AS STRING FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')||"_part_"||'*.csv',
      format='CSV',
      overwrite=true,
      header=true
      ) AS
      select * from `silicon-comfort-329203.YOUR-DATASET.test_external_table`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the uris options variable as `ARRAY<STRING>` and then enclose it in parentheses.  Here is an example:

```
DECLARE bucket STRING;
DECLARE uri ARRAY<STRING>;
DECLARE dateFormat STRING;
SET dateFormat = (SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%m%d%Y", CURRENT_DATE('America/New_York')));
SET bucket = CONCAT('gs://my-integrations/foo/bar_', dateFormat, '.csv');
SET uri = [bucket];

CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE myds.foo_bar_ext
OPTIONS (
  format = 'CSV',
  uris = (uri)
);
```

[External Table Options](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#external_table_option_list)

[image]